# Why FirebaseMessaging getToken() not working?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I made a messaging class extending FirebaseMessagingService and found that onNewToken method was working fine.

But, when I used the sample code for FirebaseMessaging class to get the current Firebase Token, I ran into an error: *error: cannot find symbol method getToken()*.

What am I missing?
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

DataManager.java

```
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;


public class DataManager {


public static String registerGoogleServiceInBackground( final OnDataManagerRegisterGooglePlayServiceListener listener )
    {
        boolean isEnabledPlayService = true;
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable( getContext() );
        {
            if( GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError( resultCode ) )
    
            {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog( resultCode, (Activity) getContext(), PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST ).show();
    
            } else {
                Log.i( "MainActivity.java|checkPlayService", "|This device is not supported.|" );
            }
    
            isEnabledPlayService = false;
        }

        if( isEnabledPlayService )

        {

            if( TextUtils.isEmpty( registrationId ) )
                 {
                        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

                        @Override
                        protected String doInBackground( Void... params )
                        {
                            String msg;
                            try {
                                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                                      if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                         Log.w(tag, "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
                                         return;
                                         }

                                      // Get new FCM registration token
                                      registrationId = task.getResult();
                                     }
                                  });
                                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + registrationId;
                                    Log.d("Device registered", "|" + registrationId);
                            
                            } catch( Exception ex ) {
                                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                            }

                        return msg;

                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute( String msg ){
                        if( listener != null ) listener.onFinish( true, registrationId );
                            Log.i( "MainActivity.java | onPostExecute", "|" + msg + "|" );
                        }
                    }.execute( null, null, null );
                            return "";
                    }
                 } else {
                           if( listener != null ) listener.onFinish( true, registrationId );
                       return registrationId;
                     }
                    } else {
            Log.i( "MainActivity.java | onCreate", "|No valid Google Play Services APK found.|" );
            if( listener != null ) listener.onFinish( true, registrationId );
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"?  What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: When I try to build this code in Android Studio, build keeps failing saying 'cannot find symbol variable getToken'

Comment: Have you imported "FirebaseMessaging" class?

Comment: Yes.  I've added at the first line.

Comment: `getToken` is a function, so you need to _call_ it by adding `()` after it. So `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken`  should be `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()`.

Comment: Sorry. It was just typo and I corrected. But I still got an error : Can not find method getToken();  Does this error have to do with the Firebase version?  I've implemented as follows:
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'

Answer (score 3):

I think like handsben above that the problem lies in the dependencies. I have an alternative suggestion that worked for me. This was the error message supplied by android studio

```
Cannot resolve method 'getToken' in 'FirebaseMessaging'
```

In the dependencies (in the app-level build.gradle) was this line

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
```

When I clicked on it android studio suggested I change it to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.5'
```

which I did and the error went away.
Hope this could work for you too

Comment: solved here, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with firebase dependencies versions mismatch. Try to import the BoM for the Firebase platform. By using BoM your app will always use compatible versions of the Firebase Android libraries.

In your app-level build.gradle you can try add the following;

```
dependencies {
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.0')

    // Declare the dependencies for the Firebase Cloud Messaging and Analytics libraries
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

You can following the instructions here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Cheers!